# Prove that $11^{10^3} \equiv 1 \pmod{10^4}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

In trying to prove that $11^{10^3}\equiv 1 \pmod {10^4}$. I have tried to rewrite the expression so that I can use Fermats little theorem using exponentional rules. Also I know that $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$. But I just get stuck in a circular argument going back to the original expression proving nothing. I think this should be fairly easy to prove, I just cant figure it out.

I also plugged this into wolframalpha and I think in general that $11^{10^a} \equiv 1 \pmod {10^{a+1}}$.

Comment: Do you mean $11^{103}$? Or maybe $11^{10^3}$? Or what??

Comment: Sorry, now the typos are fixed. Yes I mean $11^{10^3}$.

Comment: Use `$x=y\pmod{n}$` for $x=y\pmod{n}$.

Comment: First, can you prove $11^{10}\equiv1\pmod{10^2}$?

Comment: Yes and now I see why it works.

Comment: It is highly likely that a very similar question has been handled already. The close to 200 hundred questions lumped [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/81228?lq=1) and being linked to [this mother thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/11619) cover a lot of techniques. Admittedly this congruence is a special case better handled by binomial formula as in the answers. That technique has also been used many times on the site already, but in my opinion high rep answerers would be better placed to find a good duplicate.

Comment: I will not use that mother thread as a duplicate target this time due to the special feature. Anyway, take a look Lord Shark the Unknown's second comment (third above this). I recommend induction on $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generalized version of copper.hat's answer:
\begin{align}
11^{10^a}\pmod{10^{a+1}}&= (10+1)^{10^a}\pmod{ 10^{a+1}} = \left[\sum_{i=0}^{10^a}\binom{10^a}{i}10^i\right] \pmod{ 10^{a+1}} \\
&= \left[\sum_{i=0}^{a}\binom{10^a}{i}10^i\right] \pmod{ 10^{a+1}}\\
& = \left[1+\sum_{i=1}^{a}\frac{10^{i-1}(10^a-1)\ldots (10^a-i)}{i!}10^{a+1}\right] \pmod{ 10^{a+1}}\\
&= 1.
\end{align}
Here, the last step follows because $\frac{10^{i-1}(10^a-1)\ldots (10^a-i)}{i!}$ is an integer. To prove this, we note that $\binom{10^a}{i}=\frac{10^{a}(10^a-1)\ldots (10^a-i)}{i!}$ is an integer. The factors of $i!$ that are cancelled with the factors of $10^a$ are multiples of $2$ and $5$. Clearly, the largest divisor of $i!$ that cancels with $10^a$ is less than $2^{i-1}5^{i-1}=10^{i-1}$. Therefore, $\frac{10^{i-1}(10^a-1)\ldots (10^a-i)}{i!}$ is also an integer.

Comment: Whys is $\left[\sum_{i=0}^{10^a}\binom{10^a}{i}10^i\right] \bmod 10^{a+1} = \left[\sum_{i=0}^{a}\binom{10^a}{i}10^i\right] \bmod 10^{a+1}$

Comment: $\binom{10^a}{i}10^i$ is a multiple of $10^{a+1}$ for $i>a$, so $\binom{10^a}{i}10^i\bmod 10^{a+1}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe consider $(1+10)^{10^3} = \sum_{k=0}^{10^3} \binom{10^3}{k} 10^k = \sum_{k=0}^{3} \binom{10^3}{k} 10^k \mod 10^4$?

It is straightforward to verify by computation that $10^4 \mid \binom{10^3}{k} 10^k$ for $k=1,2,3$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Sorry, forgot the mod part

Comment: Please, why the downvote?

Comment: This time I didn't downvote, but I might have. For we have hundreds of similar threads, and the high rep users arguably should know to search for one. My "favorite" duplicate target is not optimal this time, so I didn't dv, but my general sentiment against duplicates has not changed. This time I was busy trying to help the asker typeset the question properly, and started thinking about finding a duplicate later. May be others share my sentiments. Go figure?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for comment. I am not against downvotes, just without knowing why serves little purpose. I have had limited success in the past searching for answers.

Comment: I really wish there were a better way of handling these different ideas on how the site is to be used. The community is too large for a round table discussion, and passions run high as people with diametrically opposite points of view think they are right. Well, that's for meta.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I can appreciate the frustration, albeit I am a source of such. Generally my goal is to assist the OP, sometimes there is some personal enjoyment if the answer seems to be slightly different than expected...

Comment: When I wrote 'searching for answers' I meant 'searching for duplicates'.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I have taken your comment to heart, and am spending more time looking for duplicates before answering. However, I must confess that my success rate for locating suitable answers (that I am sure must exist) is pretty low. I have looked at the list of generalisations, etc.

Comment: Appreciated! Searching is not always easy. Have you tried [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%2411%5E%7B10%5E3%7D%20%5Cequiv%201%20%5Cpmod%7B10%5E4%7D%24&p=1)? You can copy/paste a TeX-snippet there. It often works well, but is no wonderdrug.

Comment: People in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question) can give more tips. I don't frequent it, but if you comment there some of the regulars can probably help.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks. Interesting search engine!